# Where are windows updates on a Chinese Windows 7 PC?

Tags: windows-7

I absolutely am unable to find where Windows 7 Updates are located on a Chinese PC. Is there a way to bring up the GUI from the command prompt? Or if anyone can give me any instructions, it would be appreciated!

I found out that this is an OEM install. I don't know if that changes anything.

UPDATE: I found windows update. It looks different, and seems to fail. Is this a normal Windows Update screen or is there any english reference for this that exists?
[image: update2]

Comment: Maybe it would help if you explained what exactly you're trying to achieve here. Is it Win7 Ultimate and you're trying to install the English language pack? Is reinstalling Windows from scratch not an option? Can't you ask someone who can read Chinese?

Comment: That screenshot is for the Windows Update troubleshooter. Something seems to have failed, though I cannot tell what. Check out my answer, I've added some alternative options there. Specifically, try option #2.

Comment: @Indrek Thanks, but the window never comes up. Seems like there is something fundamentally wrong with this installation. A MSE scan doesn't show any malware, yet there may be some system corruption

Comment: Yeah, definitely sounds like something's wrong. Try running `sfc /scannow` from an elevated command prompt and see if it reports any problems.

Comment: @Indrek Thanks, but it couldn't find anything wrong. Appreciate the help btw

Comment: No problem, but unfortunately I don't think I can offer any more advice. Further, this is starting to look like a pretty localised problem (ie. something specifically wrong with your computer), and your question might get closed because of that. I'd recommend getting help from wherever you got the computer from. Or simply wipe the hard drive and install Windows from scratch, because who knows what else is messed up besides Windows Update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a couple of options:

1. You can start Windows Update from the command prompt with the following:

   ```
   control /name Microsoft.WindowsUpdate
   ```

   For a full list of Control Panel applets you can run from the command line, see here:
   http://pcsupport.about.com/od/tipstricks/a/control-panel-command-line.htm
2. Navigate to http://update.microsoft.com, that should open Windows Update automatically
3. Open Control Panel, then locate Windows Update by its icon:

   [image]

   If the Control Panel is set to show icons by category, click on the first one (System and Security; its icon is the four-colour shield and 3D pie chart), Windows Update should be fourth under that category.
4. If you have the Action Center icon (little white flag) in the notification area, right-click on it, the last option in the context menu should open Windows Update.

Comment: Odd, it should have worked. Anyway, do you have the Action Center icon (little white flag) in the notification area? If yes, right-click on it, the last option should open Windows Update.

Comment: yes it brings up something that looks like Windows Update, but it's very strange..

Comment: @ChrisHarris Strange how? Can you post a screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be a direct way to open it from the command line. However, you should be able to get to it from Control Panel. If you want to open Control Panel from the command line, type `control` from the command line.

Comment: I can open control panel, but I cant read anything there. Further, nothing there points to windows update

Comment: @ChrisHarris If the Control Panel shows icons, then Windows Update should be the last one. If it shows categories, click on the first one (System and Security, the icon is the four-colour shield and 3D pie chart), then Windows Update should be the fourth one in the list. Alternatively, post a screenshot of what the Control Panel looks like, so we can try and guide you from there.